# What to do when absolute positioned jCarousel overlaps second div on smaller browser window

Tags: css, jcarousel

If you view this site and reduce the size of your browser window, the top two primary blocks (image carousel and "Latest News") will overlap: http://africanstudies.stanford.edu/

I have tried a number of methods to fix this, but I can't come up with anything that doesn't overlap and look awful. (I also had to add some width/height settings to the carousel because I think there may be a bug with jCarousel where the entire image is not displayed if you don't specify the height for example.)

What I'd really like to happen is both the blocks scale down as the browser scales, but I'm afraid that's beyond my current capabilities.

Anyone have any thoughts on how to handle this? I can post HTML/CSS, but it's pretty ugly.

Answer (score 0):

You've set the height on `#views_slideshow_singleframe_main_home_banner_cycle-block_1` to `270px`, if you remove that then it seems to be fine. Btw, you have essentially the same issue in the horizontal direction, i.e. at a certain width the slide show overlaps the Latest News.

Comment: Thanks for responding; I removed the CSS with the height settings but I sense there was a second issue I was not aware of. Hopefully that's fixed now, but I really am looking to also fix the overlap you mentioned. Any thoughts on how to handle that as the browser size shrinks?

Comment: Yeah, that's coming from the width set on `#block-views-home_banner_cycle-block_1`

Comment: I don't have a width set on that ID. I unrolled the CSS BTW to make it easier to debug.

Comment: Actually I guess it's the `span6` class that's set on that div that the width is being applied to, which is coming from the bootstrap styles. For instance when `@media (max-width: 979px) and (min-width: 768px)` matches, `.span6` is getting a width of 460px set on it.